# Pauses between commands in simple console C# app

Tags: c#, console-application

Is there any easy how to e.g. have 1 second delay between commands? I can only think of some large cycles. I know about thread.sleep but it is not what I am looking for - I would like to just use something else without relation to threads.
Thanks for any idea

Comment: Why don't you want to use Thread.Sleep()?

Comment: Why thread.sleep wouldn't work? What kind of behaviour you would like to have instead?

Comment: I'm still confused. What do you mean "I would like to just use something else without relation to threads"? I mean your console app is fundamentally a thread, so why not just use Thread.Sleep() to pause it?

Comment: Sounds to me like Thread.Sleep is exactly what you're looking for, but you don't know it yet...either that or you need to rephrase yourself a bit.

Comment: Take look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486672/c-timer-slowing-down-a-loop/3486691#3486691

Answer (score 2):

I *think* that you are after something like [yield return](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0%28VS.80%29.aspx).

This allows you to have the pass control back to the calling code and then can carry on through your app. The link has a good example of its use.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (string x in Foo())
        {
            Console.WriteLine (x);
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable Foo()
    {
        yield return "Hello";
        yield return "there";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use System.Diagnostics Stopwatch class in a loop

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx for reference and usage examples