# C# Windows Service Timers not Firing

Tags: c#, windows, service, timer

I am using a `System.Threading.Timer` in Windows service to execute a method periodically.
The timer fires only once, it does not fire. Can anyone please help.

Below is the code

```
private TimerCallback timerDelegate;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(DoWork);
    serviceTimer =  new Timer(timerDelegate, null, 1000,Timeout.Infinite);
}

private void DoWork(object state)
{
    GetMessages();
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486672/c-timer-slowing-down-a-loop/3486691#3486691

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final parameter (`Timeout.Infinite`) in your function call tells it to use an infinite interval between the first time it fires and each subsequent time. So it'll fire once after 1 second and then never again. You should probably do:

```
serviceTimer = new Timer(timerDelegate, null, 1000, 1000);
```

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1cy0c7zw.aspx):

> The time interval between invocations of callback, in milliseconds. Specify Timeout.Infinite to disable periodic signaling.

Comment: i changed it.. it is still not firing.. am i missing anything? do i have to do anything else in Windows service?

Comment: @srikanth: You're sure it's not firing after you made the suggested change? Is something in your `GetMessages` method disposing of the timer or changing it in any way?

Comment: no.. the messages are actually still in the queue. I think the timer is not working.. when the start the service.. in the onStart event it is getting the messages and that's it.. the timer does not fire.

Comment: @srikanth: Where is `serviceTimer` declared?

Comment: @srikanth - so if you remove the GetMessages call and just do something else in there (I don't know, write to the Event Log or a file or something), you can confirm that it executes once (after 1 second) and never executes again?

Comment: yes.. it does not fire. Do i have to instantiate it again? and assign to variable? do you have any examples?

Comment: @srikanth - like Joel B Fant asked, where is serviceTimer created? Are you creating it in that function? If so, it might be getting garbage collected.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by that? I am creating service timer in OnStart.. as you can see in my code.. nothing else

Comment: GetMessages is used to get messages from Queue

Comment: @srikanth - You're *instantiating* it in OnStart. But where is it *declared* (should have been more clear in my question? Is it also declared in that function? Or is it a member of the service class like timerDelegate is?

Comment: declared as class level variable // declare class-level variable for the timer
        private Timer serviceTimer;

Comment: Hrm. Then I'm stumped. Hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: hey tim, I need to pull the messages from message queue as soon as the message arrives at the queue. so i created a windows service to get the messages and using the timer to execute it every one second. is there any otherway to do other than timers? (Note: Its JMS Queues not MSMQ)

Comment: Message Queues are not my thing. Sorry. Like I said, hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: @srikanth: If you want a producer/consumer system with a queue (which it sounds like you're doing), you should use `BlockingCollection`. No timer required, and it works very well. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx. There are many examples here on SO and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The first timeout value is how long to wait for the first invocation of the callback, but the second is for repeat interval. You can set it to wait 5 minutes for the first "tick", and repeat every minute afterwards, for example.

By passing `Timeout.Infinite` as the last argument, you told it to only invoke once.

MSDN: [System.Threading.Timer constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7.aspx)

Comment: changed it to serviceTimer =
               new Timer(timerDelegate, null, 1000,1000); it still does not fire.. am i missing anything? pls help

Comment: GetMessages is used to get messages from Queue