# How to slow down a while loop inside a timer

Tags: c#, timer, while-loop, picturebox, slowdown

I need some help slowing down a while loop inside a timer. I'm making a platform game and want a picturebox (block) to move back and forth, which i have succeeded with. However, the block is moving so fast that it is making everthing else lag. Any help would be appreciated!

```
        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        while (block.Left > (ClientSize.Width-ClientSize.Width))
        {

            block.Left -= 1;
            if (block.Left == (ClientSize.Width - ClientSize.Width))
            {
                break;
            }

        }
        while (block.Right < ClientSize.Width)
        {

            block.Left += 1;
            if (block.Right == ClientSize.Width)
            {
                break;
            }  
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `Thread.Sleep(1000)` or `Task.Delay` for  injecting a delay

Comment: There is something similar to your question: [This would probably help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486672/c-sharp-timer-slowing-down-a-loop)

Comment: Get rid of the while loops so a single timer tick moves the block by one increment.  Which needs to be larger than 1, you need a *velocity* variable.

Comment: Threads did slow down the picturebox, but i can't move my main character with this solution. I'm looking for a way to make a slower continous movement without it stopping on the sides.

Comment: @HansPassant , how would i do that? I'm quite new to c# and not at all sure how to start with that solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use threads for doing that you can see sample code:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        while (block.Left > (ClientSize.Width-ClientSize.Width))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50); //how about putting sleep here for 50ms?
            block.Left -= 1;
            if (block.Left == (ClientSize.Width - ClientSize.Width))
            {
                break;
            }

        }
        while (block.Right < ClientSize.Width)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50); //how about putting sleep here for 50ms?
            block.Left += 1;
            if (block.Right == ClientSize.Width)
            {
                break;
            }  
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Threads did slow down the picturebox, unfortunately I can't move my main character with this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the interval of the timer tick. You would do this using the `Interval` property.

```
timer2.Interval = 1000; //This would make the timer tick every second.
```

The value represents the number of milliseconds between ticks.

Once you do this you can change up the code inside your tick event, so that it only moves once based on the tick event.

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (block.Left < (ClientSize.Width-ClientSize.Width)
    {
        block.Left -= 1;
    }

    if (block.Right > (ClientSize.Width-ClientSize.Width)
    {
        block.Left += 1;
    }
}
```

With this, you will be able to adjust the speed of movement with the `timer2.Interval` property.

Comment: I've tried the interval, but that makes everything stop on one side. I'm looking for a way to make a slower continous movement. Using "if" doesn't work though, makes it go to one side forever. Thanks!

Comment: The is the appropriate way to do it. However, you code is very buggy... like incorrect comparison or variable (and a delay that is way to high).